# How to pass props in a route component Element of React JS?

Tags: reactjs

Here is how my `app.js` looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import StarterScreen from './components/StarterScreen.jsx';
import LoginScreen from './components/LoginScreen.jsx';
import RegisterScreen from './components/RegisterScreen.jsx';
import DisplayScreen from './components/DisplayScreen.jsx';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
  return function App(){
    <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
    <Route component={StarterScreen} exact path="/"></Route>
    <Route component={RegisterScreen} exact path="/register"></Route>
    <Route component={LoginScreen} exact path="/login"></Route>
    <Route component={DisplayScreen} exact path="/login-props-test"></Route>
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have two major objective in the above snippet:

1. To pass the props.isLoggedIn in the code `<Route component={DisplayScreen} exact path="/login-props-test"></Route>`.
   I know there are ways to pass props while using components like:
   `<DisplayScreen isLoggedIn={true} />`
   But how do I pass it in this `Route component` element?
2. To pass the props.isLoggedIn in a function:
   the function is as follows:

> ```
> function checkLogin(props)
> {
>   if(props.Authentication===true)
>       props.history.push('/login-props-test'); 
> }
> ```

I want to pass props.isLoggedIn into this function as well. Any way to execute these two processes?

Comment: What's the goal of that? You want protected routes? If so, there's no need to pass those props to the components, you should do it in a wrapper of the route (i'll tell you how if that's what you want to achieve)

Comment: So basically I have coded all my pages in functional components and I am authenticating if the user has successfully logged in using right credentials or not. In case they have then I want to move to DisplayScreen page (which is again a functional component)

Comment: Even that the answer below will work, it's not a good practice to do it like that.
How do you know if the user is authed? Is it stored in the context?

Comment: Actually during login I will ping my backend and check up all the credentials, once backend approves I am going to pass a local boolean as a prop to the loading screen if validation is true or false. Based on that prop I am going to render my future screens. Do you know any alternatives for the same which you feel will be the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would follow this approach to protect routes (an reuse the code, which is always good)

First, create a component that will act as a Route wrapper.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuthContext } from "services/auth-provider";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...options }) => {
  const { accessToken } = useAuthContext();

  if (!accessToken) {
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />;
  }
  return <Route {...options} component={component} />;
};

PrivateRoute.defaultProps = {};

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Following this approach you can redirect to the login page if they are not authed or the token is invalid (or whatever condition you want to check) and also is fully reusable.

You can then use it like this:

```
const Router = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route component={StarterScreen} exact path="/"></Route>
      <Route component={RegisterScreen} exact path="/register"></Route>
      <Route component={LoginScreen} exact path="/login"></Route>
      <PrivateRoute component={DisplayScreen} exact path="/login-props-test"></PrivateRoute>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: wow I see, this seems to be even more interesting. Thanks for the answer! I will try this out.

Comment: Cool! If you need more help with that just ping me :)

Answer (score 1):

just use this instead

```
import React from 'react';
import StarterScreen from './components/StarterScreen.jsx';
import LoginScreen from './components/LoginScreen.jsx';
import RegisterScreen from './components/RegisterScreen.jsx';
import DisplayScreen from './components/DisplayScreen.jsx';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
    <Route component={()=> <StarterScreen your_prop={here} />} exact path="/"></Route>
    <Route component={()=> <RegisterScreen your_prop={here} />} exact path="/register"></Route>
    <Route component={()=> <LoginScreen your_prop={here} />} exact path="/login"></Route>
    <Route component={()=> <DisplayScreen your_prop={here} />} exact path="/login-props-test"></Route>
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

changed code is:

```
<Switch>
    <Route component={()=> <StarterScreen your_prop={here} />} exact path="/"></Route>
    <Route component={()=> <RegisterScreen your_prop={here} />} exact path="/register"></Route>
    <Route component={()=> <LoginScreen your_prop={here} />} exact path="/login"></Route>
    <Route component={()=> <DisplayScreen your_prop={here} />} exact path="/login-props-test"></Route>
</Switch>
```

or you can use this as well

```
<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
          <StarterScreen your_prop={here} />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/register">
          <RegisterScreen your_prop={here} />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/login">
          <LoginScreen your_prop={here} />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/login-props-test">
          <DisplayScreen your_prop={here} />
      </Route>
</Switch>
```